# Rails 5 - using enums, what to do when the enum value is a reserved word?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I have a simple enum (added in Rails 4.something)

```
enum direction_type: [:undefined, :loop, :out_and_back, :point_to_point]
```

Which works, but in the logs I see this error:

```
Creating scope :loop. Overwriting existing method Trail.loop.
```

Another one:

```
enum status: [:undefined, :new, :draft, :published]

Creating scope :new. Overwriting existing method Trail.new.
```

I am not entirely sure what these errors mean, but they don't sound good!

Should I change these enums or is there some other solution (like some clever scope rule I could add to fix them?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you cannot change the enum values, you still should be able to resolve the conflict with **enum prefix or postfix-ing**. The `_prefix` / `_postfix` option in the enum definition should leave the values of the enums untouched but affect the auto-generated boolean and bang method names **as well as scope names**.

So, something like this:

```
enum direction_type: [:undefined, :loop, :out_and_back, :point_to_point], _prefix: true
```

should generate the following scopes: `direction_type_undefined`, `direction_type_loop`, etc... which will cause no clashes with existing class methods.

See the [docs in the source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L77) for more info.

Comment: Thanks I had looked at that solution and (stupidly) assumed it would result in the prefix actually being added to the enums, but you are right it leaves the values of the enums untouched. So my solution of 15 lines of code is replaced with yours of 13 characters, lol. :)

Comment: I forgot I could do that, very useful your answer

Answer (score 0):

You should change enums if you dont want to lose native functionality of

```
:loop
```

and

```
:new
```

Comment: Yes I was worried about losing the native functionality. Maybe I could override the setter and getter for the enums...

Comment: @rmcsharry: renaming is simpler

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I think the same)

Comment: So do I, except for one problem - multiple different client applications want to display 'loop' and 'new' in their respective different UI's.  Therefore they would all have to implement the same logic to transform the values to and from the API calls. And I would have to document that in the API docs - why not just give them what they want for free?

Comment: @rmacsharry Why not exposing the values as loop and new in your API and handle it with different names internally?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, changing the enums was not something I could do - multiple different clients consume the data and it would result in confusion to change the enums to some other values. They are taking 'loop' and 'new' and displaying those values directly in the UI.

So I had to override the getter/setters in the model, like this:

```
  def distance_type=(distance_type)
    write_attribute(:distance_type, safely_in(distance_type))
  end

  def distance_type
    safely_out(read_attribute(:distance_type))
  end

  private

  def safely_out(distance_type)
    return "loop" if distance_type == "looped"
    distance_type
  end

  def safely_in(distance_type)
    return "looped" if distance_type == "loop"
    distance_type
  end
```